# Jquery ignoring empty string as value

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I was trying to use the jquery extend functionality to introduce some default values and extend them with known values. An example would be something like this:

```
var defaults = {
   email: '',
   firstName: '',
   lastName: '',
   password: '',
   gender: 'M',
   phoneNumber: ''
};

var properties = {
   firstName: 'testuser',
   gender: 'F',
   phoneNumber: null
};

var values = $.extend({}, defaults, properties);
console.log(values.phoneNumber);
```

After extending the defaults with the actual values, I would expect the phoneNumber in values being an empty string (the empty value), but instead it is null like in the properties with which I extended the defaults. Does anybody know if this is expected behaviour? If so, is there a good reason for this?

Comment: Actually that is the normal behaviour

Comment: The reason is that _null_ is not like _undefined_. `typeof null` returns object.

Comment: `null` is a legitimate value....why would you expect different behavior?

Comment: I do understand that typeof null returns 'object', so in that case it makes sense. I expected different behaviour because 'null || 3' will return 3, so in that case it is not handled as a legitimate value.

Comment: But extend has nothing to do with checking values.... it simply overwrites existing if same property exists...or adds properties that don't exist

Comment: @charlietfl can definitely agree on that. Makes sense indeed. Thanks for the explanation